# Reverse blend colors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have found the following snippet to blend two hex colors which works great. (Apologies I cannot remember the source)

```
    function blendHexColors(c0, c1, p) {
        var f = parseInt(c0.slice(1), 16);
        var t = parseInt(c1.slice(1), 16);
        var R1 = f >> 16;
        var G1 = f >> 8 & 0x00FF;
        var B1 = f & 0x0000FF;
        var R2 = t >> 16;
        var G2 = t >> 8 & 0x00FF;
        var B2 = t & 0x0000FF;

        return "#" + (0x1000000
            + (Math.round((R2 - R1) * p) + R1) * 0x10000
            + (Math.round((G2 - G1) * p) + G1) * 0x100
            + (Math.round((B2 - B1) * p) + B1)).toString(16).slice(1);
    }
```

I now want a way to reverse this process.

Does anyone know of a way to do this.

my example would be something like this

```
var blendColor = blendHexColors('#ffffff', '#ff0000', 0.5);
var unblenColors = unblenHexColors(blendColor, '#ff0000', 0.5); // result would be #ffffff
```

Comment: Make an effort to understand what this script actually does … then you should be able to figure out what the reverse operation has to look like.

Comment: I don't think there is a way back since more couples of two colors may blend into one so you can't get the original ones from just knowing the result color, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: I know the result color as well as the color I have mixed in originally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you comment I was able to fix the code and create a fiddle that show how it works (https://jsfiddle.net/zvp4sh26/)

The problem with the original code I posted is that the result of some components (like `G` and `B`) had a value of `256` (instead of `255`)

```
function unblendHexColors(c0, c1, p) {
  var f = parseInt(c0.slice(1), 16);
  var t = parseInt(c1.slice(1), 16);
  var R1 = f >> 16;
  var G1 = f >> 8 & 0x00FF;
  var B1 = f & 0x0000FF;
  var R2 = t >> 16;
  var G2 = t >> 8 & 0x00FF;
  var B2 = t & 0x0000FF;
  var d = 1 - p;
  var R3 = (R1 - R2 * p) / d;
  var G3 = (G1 - G2 * p) / d;
  var B3 = (B1 - B2 * p) / d;

  return "#" + (0x1000000
    + (R3 > 255 ? 255 : R3) * 0x10000
    + (G3 > 255 ? 255 : G3) * 0x100
    + (B3 > 255 ? 255 : B3)).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

Should work now :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, this gave me #000100 however rather than #ffffff as I am requiring, I did have to add a ) before the .toString

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I am after!

Comment: Actually.... I spoke too soon!!  Check out this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/j48xtsc0/3/ it shows the the colours come out differently if you don't have an exact red

Comment: ... actually after looking into it more it seems it is the p which is causing the issues.  If I set to 0.5 it's fine, if I choose 0.1 it them starts going funny

Comment: It would be great if you investigate it a little bit, fix the code and share it here to assist other developers :)

Comment: That's what i'm doing... unfortunately to no avail yet